Error when I'm trying to charge in Laravel Cashier Paddle
Paddle API error 'Invalid request.' occurred with validation errors ([{"field":"items.0","message":"Additional property webhook is not allowed"}])
The line is
$checkout = $user->charge('70','pro_01jant018pa45vyq1mqyf9ezye',[
    'webhook'=>'ntfset_01jap2sc8enw41rfkncjwh0ka2']);


It's telling you exactly why the request is invalid? ['webhook' => '...'] is not allowed. What exactly are you trying to do?
